# Chrome and Electron in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, electron, selenium-chromedriver

Elsewhere on the net I had seen this kind of solution for using Chromium Webdriver to inspect and test an electron app

```
ChromeOptions eApp = new ChromeOptions()
eApp.BinaryLocation = _FullBinaryPath;
eApp.AddArgument(_BinaryPath");           
RemoteWebDriver _rwd = new ChromeDriver(eApp);
```

but I get hit with the message

```
Result Message: System.InvalidOperationException : session not created exception
from disconnected: received Inspector.detached event
```

Which I have seen can be caused by the dev console being open - but I don't see that being opened here. Is there anything out there that gives any pointers on this type of approach, and more usefully on what this error means. I have the feeling that just using spectron is going to be easier, but I wanted to check out a tech I already know first.